# Custom code on woocommerce product page (in dashboard)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to add a widget or a php code, to the right sidebar in the woocommerce product page, in the wordpress dashboard?
This is on the internal page, where we add the product, its title, featured image, price, inventory, etc., it is not on the pages that customers see.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The product pages for WooCommerce already has support for a sidebar you simply need to go to Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Single and change the “Layout” option to either “Left Sidebar” or “Right Sidebar.

For more you can visit the following:

- https://www.converticacommerce.com/support-maintenance/how-to-add-custom-sidebar-to-woocommerce-pages/
- [https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-do-i-add-a-sidebar-to-my-woocommerce-product-page/#:~:text=Go%20to%20Appearance%20%3E%20Widgets%20and,to%20your%20WooCommerce%20product%20pages](https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-do-i-add-a-sidebar-to-my-woocommerce-product-page/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Appearance%20%3E%20Widgets%20and,to%20your%20WooCommerce%20product%20pages).